# How to make Settings Panel in Windows Phone 8? C# and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, winapi, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create an app with simple settings, with list boxes, etc. 
I'm using C# and XAML.
I'm trying to implement something similar to the Camera app's photo settings settings panel.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

(I've tried Stackpanel - Scrollviewer - Stackpanel - content, however, couldn't get any transition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with  ListBox,

```
              <ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}" 
                     SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelectedSetting, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SettingName}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Width="5"></TextBlock>

                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like magic! Do you know how I would make it smooth with transitions?

Comment: @Jay can you mark it as an answer if it has helped you ! i will modify the answer for transition

Comment: Ok yes, your answer definitely was what I was looking for. However, do you have any idea on how to have the transitions?

Comment: What transition you want to make? for the listbox or for the page?